# Usage of double-pointer in C

Tags: c

```
void main() {
   struct buf *head = NULL;
   foo(&head);
}

void foo(struct buf **ptr_B) {
   struct buf **ptr_A = ptr_B;
   *ptr_B = NULL;
   *ptr_A = malloc(sizeof(struct buff));
   //here checked *ptr_A != NULL, so malloc is done successfully
   if (*ptr_A == NULL) {
      return;
   }
   *ptr_B->item = 8; 
}
```

is there any possibility that *ptr_B still equals NULL?

I ran an auto check tool and it always gives a warning here, said it's a forward null risk in the line of *ptr_B->item = 8;

Comment: There are so many wrong things here, it's hard to decide where to start...

Comment: Almost every line in this code has **undefined behavior** of some kind

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a bit time to put all relevant information into the question before posting it. Making significant changes to the code you show can make all existing comments and answers useless. Please don't make your question a moving target. To make sure you post correct code, make a minimum complete verifyable example [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) If it compiles and shows your problem you can be sure that you don't need to change the question again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze the code:

```cpp
    struct buf **ptr_B;
    // advance 1 stack slot for ptr_B, ptr_B value wasnot initialized
    struct buf **ptr_A = ptr_B;
    // advance 1 stack slot for ptr_A, set ptr_A by value of ptr_B (uninitialized)

    *ptr_B = NULL;
    // dereference ptr_B (ptr_B uninitialized) and set that memory block into NULL
    *ptr_A = malloc();
    // dereference ptr_A (ptr_A uninitialized) and set that memory block into malloc()
    *ptr_B->item = 8; 
    // dereference ptr_B (ptr_B uninitialized, *ptr_B uninitialized) and use it as "struct buf"
```

Correct code:

```cpp
    struct buf **ptr_B;
    struct buf **ptr_A;

    // allocate a pointer of `struct buf*` for both `ptr_A` and `ptr_B` point to
    struct buf** temp_ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(struct buf*));
    ptr_A = temp_ptr1;
    ptr_B = temp_ptr1;

    // set the shared pointer to NULL
    *ptr_B = NULL;

    // malloc
    struct buf* temp_ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(struct buf*));
    *ptr_A = temp_ptr2;

    // Set value from `ptr_B`
    (*ptr_B)->item = 8;

    // clean up
    free(*ptr_B);
    free(ptr_B);
```